# Unable to create Solr-core in Solr-5.0.0 hosted on server

Tags: java, solr, solrj

We were creating the solr core in our aws server from the admin console of the SOLR home page but we got the below error.

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'MYCORENAME': Unable to create core [MYCORENAME] Caused by: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getRequestHandlers()Ljava/util/Map
```

The core system has been tested and found operational in locally created instance of solr.

Comment: I am getting this exception in logging
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:190)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1984)
 at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:64)
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$5.call(SolrCore.java:1751)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a permission error.
Try `bin/solr -c MYCORENAME` from the command line instead, make sure you are in the SOLR directory

Comment: ERROR: /solr/solrfiles/solr-5.1.0/server/MYCORENAME is not supported by this script
 Its the Output of that command